# Confusing, Seemingly-Impossible, yet Correct sentence

Tags: english

What does this mean?

"The girl that a man that a dog that a complex that a landlord that a friend that a cat plays with helps owns houses loved seen plays piano."

Can you make any sense out of this?

Comment: Should it be saw or sees instead of seen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Girl
  Man
    Dog
      Complex
        Landlord
          Friend
            Cat plays with
          helps
        owns
      houses
    loved
  seen
played piano
```

Or: Cat plays with a friend that helps the landlord who owns a complex that houses a dog that loved a man that had seen a girl play piano.

Comment: Nice diagram. +1

Answer (score 6):

A cat plays with a friend.

That friend helps a landlord.

That landlord owns a complex.

That complex houses a dog.

That dog loved a man.

That man SEEN/SAW a girl.

That girl plays piano.